# Efficiently determine "how sorted" a list is, eg. Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, sorting, permutation, levenshtein-distance, ranking-functions

I'm doing some research on ranking algorithms, and would like to, given a sorted list and some permutation of that list, calculate some distance between the two permutations. For the case of the Levenshtein distance, this corresponds to calculating the distance between a sequence and a sorted copy of that sequence. There is also, for instance, the "inversion distance", a linear-time algorithm of which is detailed [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~moret/jcb01.pdf), which I am working on implementing.

Does anyone know of an existing python implementation of the inversion distance, and/or an optimization of the Levenshtein distance? I'm calculating this on a sequence of around 50,000 to 200,000 elements, so O(n^2) is far too slow, but O(n log(n)) or better should be sufficient.

Other metrics for permutation similarity would also be appreciated.

---

**Edit for people from the future:**

Based on [Raymond Hettinger's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206617/efficiently-determine-how-sorted-a-list-is-eg-levenshtein-distance/8206632#8206632); it's not Levenshtein or inversion distance, but rather "gestalt pattern matching" :P

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import random
ratings = [random.gauss(1200, 200) for i in range(100000)]
SequenceMatcher(None, ratings, sorted(ratings)).ratio()
```

runs in ~6 seconds on a terrible desktop.

**Edit2:** If you can coerce your sequence into a permutation of [1 .. n], then a variation of the Manhattan metric is extremely fast and has some interesting results.

```
manhattan = lambda l: sum(abs(a - i) for i, a in enumerate(l)) / (0.5 * len(l) ** 2)
rankings = list(range(100000))
random.shuffle(rankings)
manhattan(rankings) # ~ 0.6665, < 1 second
```

The normalization factor is technically an approximation; it is correct for even sized lists, but should be `(0.5 * (len(l) ** 2 - 1))` for odd sized lists.

**Edit3:** There are several other algorithms for checking list similarity! The [Kendall Tau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) ranking coefficient and the [Spearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient) ranking coefficient. Implementations of these are available in the [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) library as `scipy.stats.kendalltau` and `scipy.stats.rspearman`, and will return the ranks along with the associated p-values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Levenshtein distance is an O(n**2) algorithm, so if you want to go faster, use the alternative fast algorithm in the [difflib module](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#module-difflib).  The *[ratio](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio)* method computes a measure of similarity between two sequences.

If you have to stick with Levenshtein, there is a Python recipe for it on the ASPN Python Cookbook:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576874-levenshtein-distance/ .

Another Python script can be found at:  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Comment: The canonical DP Levenshtein algorithm is O(n**2), but I know that many use cases allow faster algorithms, for instance the use of [vp-trees](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/blog/01164790008). I threw together an implementation of the O(n**2) algorithm that looks comparable to those recipes, but is unfortunately too slow for what I'm doing. In the meantime, I'll check out the difflib, thanks!